# Getting data from Jira to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jira, kibana, elastic-stack

What is the best way to get information about creation and closing of issues in Jira into Elasticsearch? I want to visualize the average resolution time for our issues in Kibana.

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this github project which claims to do what you are looking for , I havent tested this yet , but this is the closest to  your request.

https://github.com/DaGrisa/agile-metrics/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page, 
https://ilaesolution.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ELA/pages/31883454/Elastic+Log+For+Jira

there is a Jira Plugin called as Elastic Log. You can configure this in Your Jira Instance and information will be pushed to Elasticsearch. Later you can create visualizations and dashboards in Kibana.

Comment: I think Elastic log plugin in Jira is a plugin to see existing Elasticsearch index data within JIRA in a new tab (inside a story/bug/task etc) not to send JIRA data to Elasticsearch.